# Add Python script to Blender 2.6.1 on mac 10.6.8?

Tags: python, macos, xcode4, blender, blender-2.50

I added my Python script to the scripts folder of Blender (which were hidden) however, i'm not sure how to add the script from that point?  Eventually I want the model to be added to xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use the link supplied in the answer to your last question [How can I use models developed in Blender within an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582229/how-can-i-use-models-developed-in-blender-within-an-ios-application) it's for Blender 2.4x. Use the recent version from [iphonewavefrontloader](http://code.google.com/p/iphonewavefrontloader/) instead.

To install a Blender add-on just go to User Preferences / Add-Ons then press Install Add-On. After installation is done you need to enable the add-on. Then you should see a new menu File / Export / Obj-C or whatever it's called now. More info about add-ons can be found in [A Separately Installable Addon](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Advanced_Tutorials/Python_Scripting/Separately_Installable_Addon_New)

I played with this add-on almost 2 years ago and don't the current state. Anyway you should bear in mind that obj is limited to meshes (and material?) and does not support armatures, animations, ... If you plan to do more sophisticated 3D stuff you should consider using a game engine like Unity3D, SIO2, Bork, Unreal,

Comment: okay the last one that was the problem I was having it wasn't showing up or working with my blender version 2.6.1, thank you for your response this will immensely help me with my project :)